# Using PowerShell to execute a dynamic WebMethod

Tags: web-services, powershell

I have a nice little powershell script that works

```
$URL = $args[0]
$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $URL -Namespace webservice -UseDefaultCredential
$result = $proxy.TestWebMethod()

usage from cmd: 
powershell.exe myscript.ps1 "http://somesite.com/someservice.asmx"
```

What I want to do is also be able to pass in the method name dynamically, something to the effect of:

```
$URL = $args[0]
$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $URL -Namespace webservice -UseDefaultCredential
$result = $proxy.$args[1]

usage from cmd: 
powershell.exe myscript.ps1 "http://somesite.com/someservice.asmx" "TestWebMethod"
```

Is there some way to make it work dynamically the second way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a service to test with, but have you tried `invoke-expression` (iex)?

```
$result = iex "`$proxy.$($args[1])()"
```

Comment: `$Method = "TestWebMethod"` and then `iex "$proxy.$($Method)()" return an error `An expression was expected after '('.`

Comment: I was able to use iex but had to do it on two lines using a single quote. `>$serviceCall = '$proxy.' + $($args[1]) + '()' >$result = iex $serviceCall`

Comment: One line version: $result = iex $('$proxy.' + $($args[1]) + '()')

Comment: My solution worked for me for calling the `toUpper()` function on a string. You may need to escape the `$proxy` variable. See updated answer

Answer (score 1):

It is a little odd looking but in PowerShell V3 you can do this:

```
$proxy | Foreach $args[1]
```

You can also do it like this if the method takes no arguments:

```
$proxy."$args[1]"
```

And if you have arguments to the method:

```
$proxy."$args[1]".Invoke(<args here>)
```

Here's an example on V2 that uses a web service and takes an arg:

```
$URI = "http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?WSDL"
$zip = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $URI -namespace WebServiceProxy -class ZipClass
$method = "GetInfoByZIP"
$zip."$method".Invoke('80525')
```

Comment: I like the idea, but I can't get it to work. For testing I stored the method in a variable: `$Method = "TestWebMethod"` and then I tried `$proxy.$Method"` and nothing happened it just returned to the next line. `$proxy | Foreach $Method` returned an error.

Comment: The first approach only works on PowerShell v3. You must on v1 or v2.  With the quoted version on V2 do it this way `$proxy."$method".Invoke()`.

Comment: Got Error: you cannot call a method on a null valued expression.

Comment: I would rather do it this way, just because it's simpler, but as of right now I can only get it to work using iex

Comment: Nevermind, you must be on at least V2 to use New-WebServiceProxy.  Weird, I tested on V2 and that approach worked for me.